Commutativity of vector addition in the context of displacement addition
Why do we use addition of vectors as a mathematical model when adding displacements? One of the properties of this operation is commutativity. When we try to apply the commutative property to two displacements, we get a completely different result, because by the definition of displacement addition, the resultant displacement should be the final displacement at the end. If we change the initial displacement with the subsequent displacement taking into account the parallel transfer and apply the triangle rule to add them together, we get a very different result as if we were doing the opposite. I understand why we use vector addition as a model when we apply two forces together, the result is the same no matter which force we apply first in the context of kinematics, but it doesn't work that way for displacement. Because unlike, for example, force, the ‘addition’ of displacements is not defined as a simultaneous action of a physical process, but as a sequential one. So why is the same mathematical model used here, despite the fundamental difference?

If you're viewing vectors as displacements, then remember that two displacement vectors are considered equal if they are parallel and of the same length and direction.
We have $\vec{v}+\vec{w}=\vec{w}+\vec{v}$ as can be seen in the following paralellogram:

Note that the green vectors are the same, say $\vec{v}$, and the blue vectors are the same, say $\vec{w}$. So the orange vector represents both $\vec{v}+\vec{w}$ and $\vec{w}+\vec{v}$.

I have now realised that commutativity is possible because the vector itself is only length (modulus) and direction, the starting point is not part of the characteristic of the vector, and is therefore excluded from the essence of the mathematical model. Am I correct in my reasoning?

@Gera Exactly right!
